# Can an interface extend a struct in Solidity and what would happen as a result?

Tags: solidity

I would like to extend the interface `{function foo(){}}` with the struct `{string bar}`. What will happen and how will I be able to instantiate a member of the interface and use the parameter bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

interfaces and structs are two different types of constructs and cannot be extended.

You can declare a struct inside an interface and use it as a parameter.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

interface MyInterface {
    struct MyStruct {
        string bar;
    }
    function foo(MyStruct memory _data) external;
}

contract MyContract is MyInterface {
    function foo(MyStruct memory _data) external {
        // do something with _data.bar
    }
}
```

Additionally, you can instantiate a member of the interface by creating an instance of the contract that implements the interface, and then calling the function `foo` with a struct that contains `bar`.

```
MyStruct memory myStruct;
myStruct.bar = "Hello";
MyContract myContract = new MyContract();
myContract.foo(myStruct);
```